# Is there a way to add the current date in AWS QuickSight dashboard's title/description?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I would like to add current date (or latest reload time) in AWS QuickSight dashboard's title/description, is there a way to add the formula to text bar?

Answer (score 0):

It could be added to the description by creating a date parameter and assigning a dynamic default which gives today's date. Then you can add the parameter as follows `<<$ParameterName>>` to the description and it should show its value which would be today's date.
A dashboard's title is only set when the dashboard is created so you cannot change that (unless you publish a new dashboard daily)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using calculated fields. basically create calculated filed which will give you same current date for all your rows and you can use that field in insight visual by customizing narrative.